# How to pronounce yin and yang?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

How do you correctly pronounce `yin` and `yang` in American English?  Especially the "yang" part because I hear it pronounced as it's spelled and also I think I've heard it like "yong".

If you use IPA please also give some rhyming words because IPA doesn't practically help me.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yang) says there are two pronunciations for *yang*: either it rhymes with *hang* or it rhymes with the first syllable of *Congo*. (But it doesn't rhyme with *long*, unless you're one of these people who pronounce Don and Dawn the same.)

Comment: it's pronounced as "young". how hard is it to get it right?

Answer (score 3):

`yang` (in American English) is pronounced somewhere between "yang" (rhyming with bang) and "yong" (rhyming with bong). Think of the first sound in the word "yacht", then add a "ng" at the end. That's as close as it's going to get. But it isn't really a pure "-ong" sound.

But if that's tricky, you can say it as rhymes with "bang" or "bong". No one will mind too much.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for people on the East Coast who pronounce *Don* and *Dawn* differently.

Comment: Are you referring to my use of the word "yawn" as an example? I can switch it to something else.

Comment: Yes, *don* or *swan* would work a lot better.

Comment: I've edited it to "yacht", to keep that initial y sound for simplicity's sake. How's that?

Comment: *yacht* is fine.